# numpy.genfromtxt with datetime.strptime converter

Tags: python, numpy, ipython

I have data similar to that seen in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/4280658) and I am trying to extract the data with numpy. I am rather new to python so I tried to do so with the following code

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

convertfunc = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S:.%f')
col_headers = ["Mass", "Thermocouple", "T O2 Sensor",\
               "Igniter", "Lamps", "O2", "Time"]
data = np.genfromtxt(files[1], skip_header=22,\
                     names=col_headers,\
                     converters={"Time": convertfunc})
```

Where as can be seen in the gist there are 22 rows of header material. In Ipython, when I "run" the following code I receive an error that ends with the following:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

The full ipython error trace can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/4280768).

I am able to extract the six columns of numeric data just fine using an argument to genfromtxt like usecols=range(0,6), but when I try to use a converter to try and tackle the last column I'm stumped. Any and all comments would be appreciated!

Comment: try using read_table, which takes care of auto-detecting the type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because `np.genfromtxt` is trying to create a float array, which fails because `convertfunc` returns a datetime object, which cannot be cast as float. The easiest solution would be to just pass the argument `dtype='object'` to `np.genfromtxt`, ensuring the creation of an object array and preventing a conversion to float. However, this would mean that the other columns would be saved as strings. To get them properly saved as floats you need to specify the `dtype` of each to get a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html). Here I'm setting them all to double except the last column, which will be an object dtype:

```
dd = [(a, 'd') for a in col_headers[:-1]] + [(col_headers[-1], 'object')]
data = np.genfromtxt(files[1], skip_header=22, dtype=dd, 
                     names=col_headers, converters={'Time': convertfunc})
```

This will give you a structured array which you can access with the names you gave:

```
In [74]: data['Mass']
Out[74]: array([ 0.262 ,  0.2618,  0.2616,  0.2614])
In [75]: data['Time']
Out[75]: array([1900-01-01 15:49:24.546000, 1900-01-01 15:49:25.171000,
                1900-01-01 15:49:25.405000, 1900-01-01 15:49:25.624000], 
                dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems to work very well. I appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 4):

You can use pandas read_table:

```
    import pandas as pd
    frame=pd.read_table('/tmp/gist', header=None, skiprows=22,delimiter='\s+')
```

worked for me. You need to process the header separately since they are variable number of space separated.