# Simple Python plot -currency and dates

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to play around with some data, in particular a txt file, that has two columns. The first column is a date in the format (dd/mm/yyyy) and the second column is a value. the two columns are separated by spaces, not commas.

I'm trying to plot a simple plot, but cant seem to separate out the 2 columns.

```
   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   with open("EURGBP DATA.txt") as f:
       data = f.read()

   data = data.split('\n')

   x = [row.split()[0] for row in data]
   y = [row.split()[1] for row in data]

   fig = plt.figure()

   ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

   ax1.set_title("Plot DAta")    
   ax1.set_xlabel('x')
   ax1.set_ylabel('y')

   ax1.plot(x,y, c='r', label='the data')

   leg = ax1.legend()

   plt.show()
```

It doesn't like the format of the date I think, but I am going around in circles!

Thanks

Comment: try using `np.genfromtxt` with a converter for the date column. Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13872188/588071

Comment: can you show sample data from "EURGBP DATA.txt" file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file Looks like this:

```
2015/10/12 1
2015/10/13 2
2015/10/14 10
```

you can use this Code, to manipulate the xticks:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


with open("EURGBP DATA.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()

    data = data.split('\n')

    x = [row.split()[0] for row in data]
    y = [row.split()[1] for row in data]

index = [i for i,val in enumerate(x)]

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_title("Plot DAta")    
ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('y')
ax1.set_xticklabels(x)
ax1.plot(index ,y, c='r', label='the data')
leg = ax1.legend()
plt.locator_params(nbins=len(index)-1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: it pings out an error:

          ` x = [row.split()[0] for row in data]

            IndexError: list index out of range`

which I had before. this is why I am getting confused

Comment: you deleted the line:  data = data.split('\n'), did you? I get this error, when I do that ;)

Comment: Nope! I have the code copied exactly as above... not sure why its throwing the error up! :s
I think my spaces between the dates and values are more than 1 space apart, would that effect this?

Comment: This works for me, regardless if i use different number of whitespace and mix it with tabs. So I can not reproduce the probem :\ Are you on 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: 2.7 is the version I am currently using.

Comment: Would it matter if the numbers (RHS Column) are decimals (4dp) but that all the numbers are not of equal size?
for instance 



          `24/03/2013   0.7525
            25/03/2013   0.76`

Comment: So i have got the data from another source:


`2016-03-31,0.7927
2016-03-30,0.7859
2016-03-29,0.7843
2016-03-24,0.7893
2016-03-23,0.792
2016-03-22,0.7897
2016-03-21,0.7818
2016-03-18,0.778
2016-03-17,0.781
2016-03-16,0.7855
2016-03-15,0.7845
2016-03-14,0.7754
2016-03-11,0.7752
2016-03-10,0.7791
2016-03-09,0.7739
2016-03-08,0.7781
2016-03-07,0.7732
2016-03-04,0.7743
2016-03-03,0.7723
2016-03-02,0.7699
2016-03-01,0.7799
2016-02-29,0.78
2016-02-26,0.7882' `




and this is the code that i would like to plot in python. can anyone help?

Comment: I tried it again (using python 3.x) with your example data. And it just works fine...just replace ´´´row.split()´´´ with ´´´row.split(",")´´´ and i get a good plot of your data!